# JFrame on bluejay too small (MAC)

Tags: java, macos, graphics, jframe

So I had a project for my computer science class and since its only the beginning of the year, I can only write basic code with bluejay. My code made my picture appear perfectly when using the school's windows computer, but when trying to edit it at home on my mac, the y maximum seemed to be cut down to about 550 (at school i got it to be around 1100), and I can't see part of the picture anymore! Also, when running it, there's no scroll bar. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses.  Different computers and Operating Systems have different requirements when it comes to rendering things like Fonts.  You should make use of appropriate layout managers and (if you're extending UI components, layout hints)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be a difference in resolution between your school computer and your home computer. If you didn't set up JFrame to scale then it will be set to the size you set it to. The aspect ratio could also be off. Try changing the size of the JFrame at home.

Comment: How am I able to change the size? When i make it bigger merely by expanding the frame, the bottom is still cut off.